# Batch-updating JComponents. Need suggestions for a better (threaded) design

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a GUI in which some groups of JComponents get "batch-updated", i.e., I have a loop and for *almost* every iteration of the loop, I need to update these JComponents. So, I tried to do the updates alongside the computations in the loop but it didn't go well being that, (if I interpret correctly) the updates were "slowed down" by the computations, the effect being only the *last* update became perceptible to the user.

That's when I thought of putting all update-related code on a separate thread. First off, I created an interface called UpdatableComponent which will wrap all JComponents that must be updated:

```
public interface UpdatableComponent {
/**
 * Implementors should be the one responsible for typecasting update
 * into the appropriate objects.
 */
public void update(Object update);
}
```

So if, for instance, I want to update a JLabel

```
public class UpdatableJLabel implements UpdatableComponent{
    private JLabel l;

    public UpdatableJLabel(JLabel l){
        this.l = l;
    }

    public void update(Object update){
         l.setText((String) update);
    }
}
```

Then, my Runnable class for threading:

```
public class UIUpdateRunnable implements Runnable {

private UpdatableComponent[] forUpdating;

public UIUpdateRunnable(UpdatableComponent[] uc) {
    forUpdating = uc;
}

public void run() {
    int limit = forUpdating.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++){

    }
}

}
```

And this is where I hit a snag. How do I know what argument to pass for each UpdatableComponent's update method? I thought of maintaining an Object array, arguments, which will map an UpdatableComponent to an argument for its update method (I have a setter method for it, of course). But then that would be (1) too tightly-coupled---bad design!---and (2) too much for a thread; the loop inside run will continuously call update on each UpdatableComponent, giving it its designated argument, updating regardless whether it actually updated or not.

I can't help but feel that I may have missed a simple way to do it. Any suggestion/advice will be very welcome. Thank you.

Comment: sounds like an EDT problem (could be blocking or not on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sound like a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) is what you are looking for. The computation is done inside the method `doInBackground()`, results are `publish()`ed and `process()` then updates the components.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've used SwingWorker for JProgressBars before but I didn't know I can use them for other threading issues.

Answer (score 3):

this issue has to do with [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), there is described other basic stuff and including `@Howard` +1 suggestion about `SwingWorker`

for `Runnable#Thread` works,

```
public void update(Object update) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            l.setText((String) update);
        }
    });
}
```